# Android Studio 0.8.6 Gradle project sync failed

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I just installed the last Android Studio 0.8.6(beta) on my MacOSx Snow leopard. After creating a basic project, I have an error message

`Gradle project sync failed ....`

I added the mavenCentral() to repositories, in my build.gradle file. But it does not fix it:

this is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

The build.gradle in my android project looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.helloworld"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

Using the command line :

```
./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace
```

I otain this error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'HelloWorld'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2.
>    Required by:
>        :HelloWorld:unspecified
>   org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
>   org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
>   
>   Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Does it sync OK if you remove the `appcompat` under dependencies ? I would try updating the Android Studio to latest version `Help -> Check for update`, AS expects certain build tools version in your Android SDK install.

Comment: Use the command line to get additional information. ./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace will show likely you what's wrong.

Comment: I edited the post with the detailed error message from that command. Am I having the right gradle version? 0.12.2

Comment: Here's the error I get: C:\Users\s010792\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication>gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyApplication'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2.
     Required by:
         :MyApplication:unspecified
      > java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (no error message)

Comment: So how did you fixed it +bolski ?

Comment: Just tom mention that upgrading to the latest version of android studio ... 0.8.14 fixed the problem